# Excel : Comparing two csv files, and isolate line data from corresponding columns

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, comparator

I have two CSV files, one of 25 000 lines containing all data and one of 9000 lines containing names i need to get the data from the first one.
Someone told me that would be fairly easy using excel but i can't seem to find a similar problem.

I've tried comparisons tools, but they are not helping me isolate what i need.
Using this example

Master file :

```
Name;email;displayname
Bbob;Bbob@mail.com;Bob bob
Mmartha;Martha@mail.com;Mmartha
Cclaire;Cclaire@mail.com;cclair
```

Name file :

```
Name
Mmartha
Cclaire
```

What i need to get after comparison :

```
Name;email;displayname
Mmartha;Martha@mail.com;Mmartha
Cclaire;Cclaire@mail.com;cclair`
```

So for the names I've in my second csv, I've got to get the entire line from the master csv file.
Right now i can use notepad compare for exemple, but on 25000 lines considering what i need, it's a lot of manual labor to come. I think there is a way someone faced a similar issue.
I can't seem to find a solution right now so here I am.

Comment: What have you actually tried?  I would suggest you **import** both files into Excel, and then use `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH` to find the matching rows.  You could probably do the whole thing in `POWER QUERY`, but you can certainly do it with just formulas.

Comment: I ended up doing it with powerquery using the helped provided below. Thanks you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beforehand, excuses for the Dutch screenshots, I'm unsure about the English terms in PowerQuery, but you should be able to follow the procedure.

**Using PowerQuery:**

- Start PowerQuery

[image]

- Load both source CSV1 and CSV2

[image]

- Join Query as new

[image]

- Select both column 1 and select `Inner` option

[image]

- Result should look like this:

[image]

- Use first row as headers:

[image]

- Delete 4th column, close and load values

[image]

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot and I got what i wanted. Wasn't exactly the same especially since we're running excel 2013 here, but it was detailled enough so i could find everything.

Comment: @Zonderziel, glad it helped. Please consider to mark this question answered.